# does M1 chip supports oracle sqlplus database?

Tags: oracle, macos

**I am planning to buy a new macbook air M1.Just confused about that does it support Oracle sqlplus database because i am currently a 2nd year student of CSE.
If it supports M1 chip then how to configure it(steps require to setup oracle sqlplus data base in M1)**

Comment: Oracle isn't supported on MacOS at all. Regardless of the chip architecture

Comment: To begin with, sqlplus is a tool to access oracle database, and it is NOT a database. You can install Oracle client on a MAC and access the database somewhere else, but not on your mac. I don't think that a version of the client supporting M1 is already out, but it may become available. I'm pretty sure there will be no Oracle DB version for M1.

Comment: Users have told me the existing [Instant Client for macOS (Intel)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html) works fine on M1 chips using Rosetta.  It is unlikely that you can run a DB itself (I've not heard anyone doing it), but you can get a completely free, unlimited Oracle DB in Oracle Cloud and access that from SQL*Plus and other tools or languages on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Oracle only supports OSX for the instant client on x86 and ppc. See [the oracle download site](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html). When Oracle bought Sun, the stopped supporting the rdbms on OSX. The last support release on OSX was 10.2.0.5 on Snow Leopard and that release was not even completed because of the Sun deal.